# How to make reference to a reference in Java?

Tags: java, pointers, reference

I am trying to remove an element from Array through a customized Iterator and I need to remove an element from my array. I know it's not very practical to use array, but I have some restrictions for some reasons.

Problem is I can't create an another array with the removed element and change the reference. Because I don't have the real reference in customized Iterator Class. I need the change the real reference. Let me explain this better in code:

```
public class Iterator<E>
{
    private E[] buffer; // underlying buffer.
    private int idx; // location of iterator in buffer.
    private E last_element; // last element returned by this iterator.

    public Iterator(E[] arr)
    {
        buffer = arr;
        idx = 0;

    }

     /**
     * Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned
     * by this iterator.
     */
    public void remove()
    {
        ...
    }


}
```

I can create a copy of buffer with removing the specified element and change the buffer reference to that. But I want this remove to effect the real array. So I 
actually need to change the arr[].

Again I know this whole use of array is senseless while having the Collection hierarchy but I need a way to this in this manner. A reference to a reference is not a good terminology in this case, but I had an implementation for this in C++, and looking something for like a pointer to pointer.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a "pointer of a pointer" I see two ways : the first one is to create an array with only one element or the second one would be to create your own wrapper class containing the element.

I will give an example of the first way:

```
public class Iterator<E>
{
    private E[][] pointerToPointer;
    private E[] buffer; // underlying buffer.
    private int idx; // location of iterator in buffer.
    private E last_element; // last element returned by this iterator.

    public Iterator(E[][] pointerToPointer)
    {   
        this.pointerToPointer = pointerToPointer;
        buffer = pointerToPointer[0];
        idx = 0;

    }

     /**
     * Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned
     * by this iterator.
     */
    public void remove()
    {
        // create your new array (let's call it newArr)
        ...

        buffer = newArr;
        pointerToPointer[0] = buffer;
    }
}
```

Then when you call your iterator, you have to create a singleton array:

```
Integer[] arr = ...
Integer[][] pointerToPointer = {arr};
Iterator<Integer> it = new Iterator<>(new Integer[][]{pointerToPointer});

//use your iterator, including remove() method
...

arr = pointerToPointer[0]; //this gets the modified array
```

---

Anyways, what is preventing you to add a method to your `Iterator` class that returns the field `buffer`?

Comment: Ty, that made sense.

Comment: @AhmedSemihÖzmekik : I edited my answer but I don't think you will get notified : in your case, what is preventing you to simply add a method like `public E[] get()` that simply returns `buffer`?

Comment: This customized Iterator is an iterator over a customized collection so whoever using this iterator cannot access the underlying buffer in the Collection. So `remove()` must handle this thing by its own.

Comment: Customized collections such as Set or ArrayList use array as underlying buffer. Whole thing is just for the sake of some project, meaning that impractical.

Answer (score 1):

It is already the case in your example ...

Setting `buffer` to `arr`, allows to create a copy of the reference, to the same Array in the heap, containing the same references of all elements.

BUT the fact is you should not use array this way, if you want to remove element.

You simply should use a List of the same kind of element.

Change your implementation, to use `List<E>` instead of arrays, and you will be able to call the remove method on it, with effect on original passed instance of list.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I just need to know, Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: It would be very very dirty, but you may add a specific method to get back the modified `arr` after all the iteration and removal is done ...

Answer (score 0):

Java is pass-by-value and not pass-by-reference, meaning; you are copying data, and letting the garbage collector (GC) taking care of the rest. So you don't have pointers, which you have in C++.

This is my idea, having one bad sideeffect - the array is fixed and allocated to the array parsed to the constructor (index is removed, but replaced with null):

```
public void remove(int index) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        E[] tmp = (E[])new Object[this.buffer.length]; // Can cause issues on some types
        int x = 0; // Variable to track tmp's index counter
        for(int i = 0; i < this.buffer.length; i++) {
            if(i != index) {                
                x++;
                tmp[x] = this.buffer[i]; 
            }

        }
        this.buffer = tmp;
    }
```

Comment: But this only effects my `buffer[ ]`. I want `arr[ ]` to be changed.